# DId firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword() change the return value?

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have been using this code for a year now:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(textUser, textPassword)
.then(function(user){
  console.log('uid',user.uid)

  //Here if you want you can sign in the user
}).catch(function(error) {
    //Handle error
});
```

However I had complaints over the last 2 days of new users having trouble creating a new login. I checked the "user" variable in this code and it looked like this:

```
{
  additionalUserInfo: {
    providerId: "password", 
    isNewUser: true 
  },
  credential: null,
  operationalType:"signIn"

  user: {
    (bunch of fields...)
    uid: "xxxxx123456789",
    (bunch of fileds...)
  }
}
```

Which means that I now have to refer to uid by using user.user.uid instead of user.uid. I made this change and the code works but I have several other uses of this function and I'm wondering if this is an actual change or if I'm seeing something unusual. I have not changed this code in ages so I'm surprised in any case. Appreciate any insights.

Comment: Did you update firebase  version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

If I check the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js) for the JavaScript SDK, there have been no changes that seem related to that in at least the last few weeks (I didn't scroll back further).

I'm also pretty sure that [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword)  has returned a `Promise <UserCredential>` for at least a few years already.

I'm not sure if that type used to have a `uid` property, so I'm checking with some team members now.

---

The last relevant change I know of and can find is in [version 5.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_500_-_may_8_2018) of the SDK (release in May 2018):

> Updated the return type signature for `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, `signInWithCustomToken`, `signInAnonymously` and `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to return a promise that resolves with a `UserCredential` instead of a user.

So if you recently upgrade from pre-5.0 to a version 5.0 or later, you will indeed need to change your code to get the user data from `response.user` instead of `response`.

Comment: Yes it contain's Frank. I am using on live site. It crashes after upgrading 5.7 to higher. @fmacdee.

Comment: SDK 5.7 is really old. If you were on an even older version, then indeed that might have returned a `User` directly.

Comment: Yes it was return `User` directly before @Frank.

Comment: *Edit it was 4.7. I mentioned my first comment.

Comment: If you're upgrading from a pre-5.0 version to 5.0 or later, there was indeed a change in the return type of some methods. I included the relevant change and a link in my answer. I'm not sure if that's what OP is having though.

Comment: It looks like most users were using my gmail based auth process so this particular code has not been run in a while. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Frank - it seems the documentation has not been updated to reflect this.. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account

Comment: Good catch. I could swear I recently fixed this too, but must've been in another place. I just filed a PR for it: https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/pull/89

Answer (score 1):

Yes it changed many methods crashed too in my side. But i have to refactor all of them. It returns a type of `UserCredential` that contains `user` and other objects.

```
UserCredential: {
   additionalUserInfo: { isNewUser: boolean, profile: Object, providerId: string, username: string  },
   credential: {accessToken: string, idToken: string, providerId: string, signInMethod: string},
   operationType: string,
   user: Object
}
```

Here is my refactored example code, It also crashes `signInWithPopup()` method.

```
firebase
   .auth()
   .signInWithPopup(provider)
   .then(authResult => {
        console.log({ authResult });

        if (authResult.user) {
            this.doLogin(authResult.user);
        }
   });
```

Unfortunately refactoring the code only solution of problem. Also check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword) link for about `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`.

Comment: Thank you! I upped your answer but gave Frank the checkmark since his answer explains the when of it that might help others.

Comment: I appreciate that. he is one step ahead of me @Frank :)